# Do golden pothos, rubber plant & spider plant release oxygen at night?

Tags: houseplants, indoors, plant-recommendations, planting

Just like snake plant & money plant, is it safe to keep golden pothos, rubber plant & spider plant in bedroom during night?
Do they release oxygen during night as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its perfectly safe, though they don't produce oxygen at night time, see this Q & A  [do indoor plants produce carbon dioxide in night?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/47607/do-indoor-plants-produce-carbon-dioxide-in-night)